# Run sql on dropdownlist item selected and show sql result in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to run sql query if the user selects item from dropdownlist and put the sql result in a textbox.

The dropdown menu shows mobile models names.Onclick of a model the price should be retrieved and shown in  textbox.


I have setup the dropdownlist to load models from the table "Products"

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Price from Products WHERE Model='" +DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged+ "'", con);

 da.Fill(dt);
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
```

But nothing shows up in the textbox even if i click an item from the dropdown

Comment: Are you getting values for the data set. Try to debug the code.

Comment: yes,i can see the values

Comment: WebForm or WinForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET, then you have to set the AutoPostBack of the dropdownlist to True. Then execute your code in the dropdownlist_selectedindexchanged

Comment: Works like a charm.Thank you so much @Abusnake

Comment: but can you tell me what autopostback does?

Comment: Autopostback allows the control to automatically post the page to the server when event occures, in your case, when the selected item change

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command is invalid. It should be

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Price from Products WHERE
Model='" +DropDownList1.SelectedText+ "'", con);
```

Either

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

or

```
DropDownList1.SelectedText
```

It Should not be

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Comment: Yes,i have changed it to DropDownList1.SelectedValue .Thankyou so much @Harsha W

Comment: Without AutoPostBack it dosent work,hence @Abusnake's answer is right.Thankyou.